# Blender not responding and showing white screen

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

Blender is not responding and shows a white screen. During rendering, my screen goes blank completely and turns on after a couple of seconds, but when it turns on I see that the blender is not responding. what to do? video card AMD RX vega 64 processor Xeon e51650 3.9 ram 32GB
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjSNb.png

Comment: Are you rendering using OpenCL? Also, how many watts is your PSU rated for?

Comment: 700 W PSU yes, opencl

Comment: Yeah, ok.... The two biggest complaints I've seen so far with Vega cards involve either an insufficient PSU (yours is fine, by the way), or broken driver versions. Maybe try a few recent versions of the drivers to see if one works better (making sure to uninstall with DDU in between).

Comment: thank you man I solved this problem but now another one appeared invalid ray state

Comment: Hmmm. Some people claim AMD software causes the issue, but removing it doesn't always seem to fix it. Does it also say "split kernel error"? Is the card OC'd, or do you have an OC profile anywhere that it might be trying to use?

Comment: Does it also say "split kernel error"? - Yes. My video card is in stock

Comment: The only other recommendation I can find is to "use the pro drivers". Does that mean anything to you? (I don't have a Vega , so I can't test)

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. Thank you.